# How to sort order like last item displays first page last item using jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables for showing the item lists. And it is displaying by descending order. And It has also the pagination. So it is showing last item first at top of the 1st page. It is working fine.

But I want to show the last item at the 1st page at the bottom row. Not to the top row. Means I want to display the last item first page but bottom of the row.

This is my code:

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 2,
      "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
      'ordering'    : true,
    })
```

Here is the image bellow, as this is "desc" order it is showing the last item first. So this is displaying item created by "2020-06-01 19:08:19" at the top. But I want this display at the bottom.

[image]

Please help me how to do it using jquery datatables.

Thank you

Comment: ```"order": [ 0, 'asc' ]``` will do

Comment: If I set it to asc, the last item is showing at the bottom of the last page. I need to show at the bottom of the first page.
How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$('#example1').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
  'ordering': true
});

$("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last"));

$(document).on("click", ".paginate_button", function() {
  let page = $(this).attr("data-dt-idx");
  if (page == 1) {
    $("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last"));
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".previous", function() {
  let page = $(".paginate_button.current").attr("data-dt-idx");
  if (page == 1) {
    $("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update: As mentioned as comment, the goal is to show on every page the last item of the page at the bottom. This can be done as follows:

```js
$('#example1').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
  'ordering': true
});

$("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last"));

$(document).on("click", ".paginate_button", function() {
    $("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last")); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update 2: As mentioned as comment, the last item should also be displayed at the bottom of the table when using the "search" or "show items" functionality. This as well as all other desired results can be done most easily by using the callback function [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback). For testing the search functionality, search for "test".

```js
$('#example1').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
  "ordering": true,
  "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
       $("#example1 tbody tr:first").insertAfter($("#example1 tr:last"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a nice code. But it is showing only the first page last row at the bottom. So first page is OK. I want, other pages will be the same sorting order. How can I do it please?

Comment: @Webdeveloper011 I've just updated my answer with a solution for this.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code. It is working fine but when I show 10 entries or something, It is not working. 

how can the "shows entries" and "search" workable please?

Comment: @Webdeveloper011 I've just updated my answer with a solution for all requirements. If this will answer your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as answered/solved.